# Optimizing k-means for "theming" an image

Tags: image, k-means, theming

I would like to write an application that takes an image and re-maps the colors to a specified color scheme.  Unsure how to do this, I've been having fun experimenting with different ideas.

One idea is to perform a k-means clustering of the colors in the images, then translate the centroids to colors specified by the theme, followed by another transform function if necessary to get each component between 0-255.

I want to optimize the starting k values, so I thought to present a GUI which allows the user to select 6-9 colors with a color picker before running the algo.

Does anyone know a better way to choose the starting k, which does not require user intervention?

Comment: Some options for starting values are discussed on Wikipedia.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: Yes, thank you.  However, I suspect there are better answers given the domain.